# MP3 Manager for Wordpress

Tags: custom-post-types, uploads, audio

Looking for the following functionality, there does not seem to be a single way to do this, at least not that I was able to find. I would gladly pay for a plugin that did all of this to save me the time of writing one.

This is for a bands' site, so keep that in mind.

- Create a new post type of Albums
- Allow admins of the site, in a user friendly way, to upload multiple MP3 files at once.
- Parse ID3 tags from the albums.
- Using the files' ID3 tags, create a post of the Album title if one does not exist.
- When the album post type for each individual album is clicked, it displays all of the tracks and users can play these tracks from the site or download them.

Does this functionality (or something similar) currently exist? I really appreciate any guidance :)

MG

Answer (score 1):

Try this theme I helped build: http://upthemes.com/themes/garage-band/ It does everything you are asking.